# Why doesn't my javaScript work when I echo it out in php?

Tags: javascript, php

I have a test file and when I run this script all I see is a blank page. I'm supposed to see a red banner that slides down from the top and says "there was an error". I've already tried echoing each line. I still have the same problem. What am I doing wrong?

```
<?php
echo '<script language="javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){

   $(this).notifyMe(
      "top", 
      "error",
      "", // Title
      "there was an error", 
      300; 
      3000; 
   );

 });
 </script>';

?>
```

Comment: Have you checked the browser console for errors?

Comment: you should use PHP with PHP and JS with JS, why the mix like that? Blank page, use error reporting and look at your console.

Comment: Pointy, yes. And now I see I have syntax errors. I think I have it from here.

Comment: if last two number are parameters to your function as well, should be `300, 3000` not `300; 3000;`

Comment: @Fred-ii-  Because the JavaScript is being ran inside of another php block I didn't post. I don't want to break out of php just to run some JavaScript. I'd rather echo it out. It's easier for me to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `;` inside notifyMe()

```
$(this).notifyMe(
  "top", 
  "error",
  "", // Title
  "there was an error", 
  300,
  3000 );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
echo '<script language="javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){

   $(this).notifyMe(
  "top", 
  "error",
  "", // Title
  "there was an error", 
  300, 
  3000
   );

 });
 </script>';

?>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.